# Accidentally deleted my Windows 8 boot entry from dual boot with EasyBCD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu with a live USB and it's running great, but I had one problem, Windows was always booting. I tried to set up a dual boot with EasyBCD, but I deleted my Windows 8 boot entry.

Through GRUB I can choose Windows Boot Manager, but I get this error:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. 
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next." 
  3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

    File: \Boot\BCD 

    Status: 0xc0000098 

    Info: The Windows Boot configuration Data file does not contain a valid OS entry.
```

I tried to rerun a Windows 8 install from USB, but only the Ubuntu GRUB launches, even after I changed the boot order.

I tried to fix it with Boot-Repair and got this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8883078/

For now I can't do the bootrec method.

So is there a way to "re-enable" Windows 8 from GRUB?

Comment: Boot-Repair can only fix a few minor Windows issues. You normally need a Windows repair flash drive and go into Windows repair console to fix Windows issues. Grub really only boots working Windows. And EasyBCD with UEFI often creates more confusion. Not really required as you should be able to boot from UEFI or one time boot key if you do not use grub menu. But EasyBCD may be able to fix BCD issues. You also show a wubi install. That does not work wit gpt partitioned drives which all UEFI systems have.

Comment: have you find any solution............ i am facing same issue, i have also deleted windows 10 entry from easyBCD......... NOW UNABLE TO BOOT, its saying winload.efi missing.

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Insert the Windows 8 usb install

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
dd if=/media/user/windows-usb of=/windows.iso
apt-get update
apt-get install unetbootin
```

Run Unetbootin.

Select the Diskimage option.

Then browse for /windows.iso

Under Type select Hard Disk

Leave / for the Drive.

Press OK

Restart your computer.

Select Unetbootin in the Grub 2 menu.

When the computer boots off Windows 8 iso.

Press the Troubleshoot option.

Select Advanced Options.

Select Command Prompt.

Recreate the Boot Configuration Data store:

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s v: /f ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the same error message,  but I had no windows installation disc. I couldn't boot Ubuntu either. I thought everything was lost. So then I used Ubuntu live USB which I had and chose to "Try Ubuntu before installing"  and performed boot repair and finally I could get Ubuntu working. (finally relieved that something was working). Then I added windows option to the Ubuntu grub menu. I got windows 8 loader option in the grub while booting but same error when I select it. I googled a lot but found no solution and I  gave up. But finally after a few days I realized something and tried it. It worked right.

THE  SOLUTION  : EasyBCD actually creates a backup of your BCD file. (or you would have been prompted to create one when you run the software)

I could access windows files from the drive in Ubuntu. Then I searched for the location where easybcd was installed and  and found backups of the bcd file. (gave me little hope that something could be possibly done)

Then I went to the folder "Root" of windows and found a file named BCD. I copied the file to other directory (just in case if I needed  it later).

Then I removed the BCD File (I didn't know if it was advisable to do it) and copy pasted the .bcd backup file into  the root folder.(The file had a name like EasyBCD Backup(-date-).bcd    )

Then I renamed the file as BCD ( same as the one I deleted) without the extensions .bcd  (the file I deleted was plainly called BCD)

After that restarted the laptop and chose the windows option from the grub and............ To my surprise..................  it worked.

It was a great relief as I was very new to all these things and had completely lost hope.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same issue and have fixed it properly. I followed the instructions from Windows:

1. Create a USB boot of your Windows (the same as your current Windows).
2. Access the boot menu and choose to boot from USB.
3. Choose the language and go to next, then click **Repair your computer**.
4. go to **Troubleshoot**, then cmd, and type the following commands.

   ```
    bootrec /rebuildbcd
    bootrec /fixmbr
    bootrec /fixboot
   ```

I hope you can fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked correct settings using Recovery Center? If not, try these steps:

1. Press Windows Key + C.
2. Click Settings, and then Change PC Settings ->> Update & Recovery ->> Recovery ->> Get Started.

Detailed diagnostic info [published here](http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/windows-8-boot-error-bcd,103829.html).