# Accidentally deleted windows boot partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

When setting up a fresh ubuntu, I accidentally deleted the windows boot partition, now Windows is not available in the boot menu. But through Fedora I still have access to the C drive and I have ad ubuntu live stick and a backup of windows c drive in 2 separate external disks.

I know there are questions on this but I have searched for hours and nothing worked.

Preferably I also do not want to delete the whole disk, only as last thing to do.

Here is what I tried:
I tried to download the windows10.iso on fedora and boot it using a tool called ventoy. But when running the iso on it, it says it is broken and can't run. I also tried the ubuntu repair-boot utility using the live usb but it did not find the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the boot partition? What version did you install? I installed 22.04 the other day and when I ran `sudo update-grub` the windows partition didn't show up but there was a message about os-prober being disabled. I had to edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to the end of the file and after saving the changes, I had to run `sudo update-grub` and then it showed windows boot loader recognized in the output. Now, I get a grub menu with a Windows boodloader option.

Comment: To be clear, after I did a clean, dual boot install of 20.04, I would boot the machine and it would go straight to Ubuntu with no boot options. I'm pretty sure the bios didn't show a Windows option either. After I made the changes and updated Grub, I now get a Windows bootloader option on the Grub menu.

Comment: You can [read about the Grub changes here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix). I know this also affects Arch and Manjaro and I believe I found the fix on a Redhat or Fedora forum, I can't remember.

Comment: Yes I am sure I deleted it, I accidentally pressed delete and now it is just unallocated free space. It being deleted I dont even have an option to get into windows recovery.

Comment: Have you [tried using WoeUSB](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu)?

Comment: Here is a [more detailed alternative method of using WoeUSB](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/easily-create-windows-10-bootable-usb-ubuntu).

Comment: Also, there are [some answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547167/accidentally-deleted-my-windows-8-boot-entry-from-dual-boot-with-easybcd?rq=1) to help after you get WIndows recovery booted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the only fix after hours of research was to use a live ubuntu usb, download a windows .iso, wipe my whole drive completely and reinstall again.

But this was only the right choice since I have a backup of all OS I use. Whoever encounters that problem should choose this method to safe time and frustration.